# How to store variadic functions inside a vector to be called during construction of a class?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm not sure if what I am asking is possible as I think I am mixing up compile time and run time operations.

Say I have a class `ExClass`. And This class has 10 rows of widgets to add to a panel. Before the template implementation, I would do:

```
void ExClass::addRow0()
{
  this->addWidget(widget1,row,col); //where row and col are different numbers, ex 0,0
  this->addWidget(widget2,row,col); // 0,1
  this->addWidget(widget3,row,col); // 0,2
  this->addWidget(widget4,row,col); // etc.
}

void ExClass::addRow ... 10(){ ... }
```

I would then have the constructor of the class look like this:

```
ExClass::ExClass()
{
  addRow0();
  addRow1();
  .
  .
  .
  addRow10();
}
```

I then decided to make variadic functions as private functions in `ExClass` that would take any number of widgets and build the rows automatically like this:

```
const int MAXCOLSIZE = 2;

template<typename T>
void addToWidget(T* widget,int row,int size)
{
  int col = std::abs(size - MAXCOLSIZE);
  this->addWidget(widget,row,col,Qt::AlignHCenter);
}

template<typename T>
void addRow(int row, T* widget)
{
  this->addWidget(widget,row,MAXCOLSIZE,Qt::AlignHCenter);
}

template<typename Widget, typename... T>
void addRow(int row, Widget *w,T*...t)
{
  constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(T);
  addToWidget(w,row,n);
  addRow(row,t...);
}

template<typename T>
void addSingle(int row, T *widget)
{
  this->addWidget(widget,row,0,1,MAXCOLSIZE+1,Qt::AlignVCenter);
}
```

The reason I did it this way, is that I wouldn't have to create 10 functions of `addRowN` to be called in the constructor. It would then save me a little bit of coding and hassle. However, it did make my constructor look like this:

```
ExClass::ExClass()
{
  addRow(0,widget1,widget2,widget3);
  addRow(1,widget4,widget5,widget6);
  addSingle(2,widget7);
  addRow(3,widget8,widget9,widget10);
  .
  .
  .
  addRow(10,widget23,widget24,widget25);
}
```

Which thinking about it now, is a lot less readable and in some places can get crazy. So I may revert back to the original way and call it via the special private vector that I created:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> rowFuncs = {
  std::bind(&ExClass::addRow0,this),
  . 
  .
  .
  std::bind(&ExClass::addRow10,this)
};
```

However, before I go back to that, I was wondering if there was a way I could pass my variadic function into a vector in the same way? I did try:

```
std::vector<std::function<void(...)>> rowFuncs;
```

However it doesn't like that it doesn't know what type the parameters are and I cannot store them. So I am wondering if what I am trying to do is even possible? It would be great if I could break it down into a function so I can clean up my constructor so it's not 10+ lines of code and instead a function which calls a vector of functions to be called like I did with the other implementation:

```
void ExClass::buildLayout()
{
  for(const auto& fn : rowFuncs)
    fn();
}
```

then my constructor will happily look like:

```
ExClass::ExClass()
{
  buildLayout();
}
```

I have `buildLayout` working in the original function implementation. However I would like to know if this is even possible to do with my variadic function implementation. If anyone has any suggestions or if this is even possible I would appreciate that!

EDIT: I should mention that `ExClass` in this case, has 25 unique widgets. All private members of the class.

Comment: Are you adding the same widget always or it depends on the row ?

Comment: @Midren they are different widgets. Every single row carries 1-3 unique widget. In this case, `ExClass` contains 25 unique widgets.

Comment: You cannot just put these new functions, as std::function should know the input types, but you can previously bind them. Something like this:
std::vector<std::function<void()>> funcs;
funcs.emplace_back(std::bind(&ExClass::addRow, this, 0, widget1, widget2, widget3)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice from @Midren's comment. I was able to achieve what I wanted. However, I needed to add the template definition as well. This was the working example:

```
class ExClass
{
  public:
    ExClass();

    void constructLayout();

  private:

    const int MAXCOLSIZE = 2;

    template<typename T>
    void addToWidget(T* widget,int row,int size)
    {
      int col = std::abs(size - MAXCOLSIZE);
      this->addWidget(widget,row,col,Qt::AlignHCenter);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void addRow(int row, T* widget)
    {
      this->addWidget(widget,row,MAXCOLSIZE,Qt::AlignHCenter);
    }

    template<typename Widget, typename... T>
    void addRow(int row, Widget *w,T*...t)
    {
      constexpr std::size_t n = sizeof...(T);
      addToWidget(w,row,n);
      addRow(row,t...);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void addSingle(int row, T *widget)
    {
      this->addWidget(widget,row,0,1,MAXCOLSIZE+1,Qt::AlignVCenter);
    }

    Widget *widget1 = new Widget();
    Widget *widget2 = new Widget();
    Widget *widget3 = new Widget();
    Widget *widget4 = new Widget();

    std::vector<std::function<void()>> rowFuncs = {
      std::bind(&ExClass::addRow<Widget,Widget>,this,0,widget1,widget2),
      std::bind(&ExClass::addSingle<Widget>,this,1,widget3),
      std::bind(&ExClass::addSingle<Widget>,this,1,widget4)
    };
};
```

You can then construct the layout like this:

```
void ExClass::constructLayout()
{
  for(const auto& fn : rowFuncs)
    fn();
}
```